# Behavior of delete this pointer in C++

Tags: c++, this, this-pointer

I am trying to explore this pointer in c++ .
I have created a pointer to class object and caling a function to delete the current object but the behavior is unexpected.

Why output of the last print statement is 
x= 0 , y= 6.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
private:
  int x;
  int y;
public:
  Test(int x = 6, int y = 6) { this->x = x; this->y = y; }
  void setX(int a) { x = a; }
  void setY(int b) { y = b; }
  void destroy()  { delete this; 
 }
  void print() { cout << "x = " << x << " y = " << y << endl; }
};

int main()
{ 
  Test *obj = new Test();
  Test objs;
  obj->print();
  obj->destroy();

  obj->print();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Behavior of deleting `this` is undefined. At least behavior accessing it afterwards is undefined.

Comment: What behavior did you expect?

Comment: I understood that the behavior is undefined after deleting this pointer.
But why the value is set as x=0 and y=6

Answer (score 3):

Deleting `this` is legal , which calls the destructor of class

However, if the object was not allocated using `new`, it will be a Undefined Behavior

But you have to be absolutely sure that this will be last member function invoked on this object and none of of your member function (after the `delete this` line) gets called through `this` object, since `this` will become a dangling pointer, which should not be dereferenced.

If you do these, the behavior will be undefined, so can see anything in your output.